# Count No of column value matched and not matched in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset where in I am trying to find the count of values matched in a column and count of values not matched. Also I am trying to find out same and different values .
Eg.

```
ID  F1 F2 F3   
A1  B1  D1  10  
A1  B1  D1  10  
A1  B1  D1  10  
A1  B1  D1  20  
A1  B1  D1  20  
A1  B1  D1  20  
A1  C1  D2  10  
A1  C1  D2  10  
A1  C1  D2  10  
A1  C1  D2  10  
A1  C1  D2  20  
A1  C1  D2  20  
A1  C1  D2  20  
A1  C1  D2  20  
A1  C1  D2  30  
A1  C1  D2  30
```

ID is always same. Column F1 and F2 will change values .
I need to find out for an ID how many Column F3 values are same and different in each set of F1 and F2.
Also what are those values.
Expected output is

```
ID  F1 F2  Count F3  Count          F3 F3 values    F3 values   
           matched   not matched    matched         not matched
----------------------------------------------------------------
A1  B1 D1  2         1              10,20           30  
A1  C1 D2  2         1              10,20           30
```

sample code I tried is :

```
select ID, F1, F2, group_concat(F3,'|') from  table 
group by ID, F1,F2.
```

After that I left joined with same table to get different values and count but not progressing well.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
A

Comment: I find the expected output difficult to understand. Is count f3 matched a count where f3 values match across ALL id/f1? the stumbling block for me is if there is an a1/d1 (id/f1) with a value of 10 then 20 no longer matches over ALL id/f1 - is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter version to your requirements:

```
select count(distinct data.F3) from data INTO @numOfF3s;

select 
    data.ID, 
    data.F1, 
    data.F2, 
    count(distinct data.F3) as 'match F3',
    @numOfF3s - count(distinct data.F3) as 'no match F3'
from  data 
group by data.ID, data.F1, data.F2
```

gives:

```
+----+----+----+----------+-------------+
| ID | F1 | F2 | match F3 | no match F3 |
+----+----+----+----------+-------------+
| A1 | B1 | D1 |        2 |           1 |
| A1 | C1 | D2 |        3 |           0 |
+----+----+----+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, solved it. Look a little complicate query:

```
select 
    ID, F1, F2,
    group_concat(if(all_groups=1,F3, null)) all_matched_F3,
    count(if(all_groups=1,F3, null)) all_matched_F3_count,
    group_concat(if(all_groups=0,F3, null)) not_all_matched_F3,
    count(if(all_groups=0,F3, null)) not_all_matched_F3_count
from (
  select 
      F3,
      count(distinct concat(ID, F1, F2)) = (select count(distinct concat(ID, F1, F2)) from data) all_groups
  from data
  group by F3
) tmp,
(select distinct ID, F1, F2 from data) groups
group by  ID, F1, F2
;
```

The query works. Can be testetd here [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=f4c29bcb3f6f36fcec7a738f8f09f718&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

All the query optimization welcome in comments